# CMake : Flex custom_command never called

Tags: c++, cmake, lex

I have some issue using CMake with Flex in a C++ project.
I use `FindFlex`and its macro `FLEX_TARGET` which generates a custom command which simply called the Flex executable to create a source file from a `.l` file.

[See macro definition from Github Cmake project](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindFLEX.cmake).

My project only consists in the `CMakeLists.txt` and my `Example.l` LEX file. Also a pair of files, Parser.hpp/Parser.cpp, which currently only contains an "I do nothing" class (constructor, destructor, that's all):

Here's the `CMakeLists.txt`:
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

```
project(PARSER)

find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)
flex_target(Scanner Example.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LexParser.cpp)

set(Parse_SRCS
    Parse.cpp
    ${FLEX_Scanner_OUTPUTS} 
)

set(Parse_INCS
    Parse.hpp
)

add_executable(Parse ${Parse_INCS} ${Parse_SRCS})

target_include_directories(Parse PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
target_include_directories(Parse PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

Problem : **`Scanner` target is never called**.

First checks :

- When I output  `FLEX_FOUND`, `FLEX_EXECUTABLE` and `FLEX_LIBRARIES` I see the module as been correctly found.
- I have tested on both Linux and Windows installations of CMake and Flex. But same here and there.
- The inner custom command should at least output a message like "*[FLEX][Scanner] Building scanner with flex 2.5.4*" proving the custom command is executed, but not. Still I have no error either.

Thank you !

Comment: Custom command is not called, if its output file(`${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LexParser.cpp`) is already exists, and newer that input(`Example.l`). Check that you haven't had output file already. Also, you can check that content of `Parse_SRCS` variable is correct (just print it with `message()`).

Comment: Checked for `Parse_SRCS` value correspond to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LexParser.cpp` which is good. And yes, I've check but no output file is blocking the dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`flex_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindFLEX.html), somewhat misleadingly, creates a [custom command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_custom_command.html) and not a [custom target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_custom_target.html).

Custom commands (unlike custom targets) are not executed by themselves, but have to be associated with a target (or another custom command) that consumes its output.

You do this by adding the output of `flex_target`, which is written by the function to the `FLEX_Scanner_OUTPUTS` variable, as a source file to your `Parse` executable. This will cause the file to be generated when that executable is built.

Note however that custom commands are always executed *at build time* (eg. when running `make`), not when running CMake.

Comment: `FLEX_Scanner_OUTPUTS` which is part of `Parse_SRCS` implies that the Flex output is set as a source file of my executable. But I've tested by writing it *eplicitly* in case the problem was that. No change.
**Indeed, you are right saying it is a pre-build process of build system**, not CMake. So I have to run 'make' to create the file. It feels weird I did not even think about that...

Comment: Sorry I missed the `FLEX_Scanner_OUTPUTS` there. I will adjust the answer accordingly.